# Better way to load data onto the GPU in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I am trying to do a comparative study across different image classification models, so I plan on training them all on the same dataset. I was wondering if there is a method in which I load the entire dataset onto the GPU once and use that to train all the models. Without having to do it for all the models using the standard `image = image.to(device)` every time I train a model. Because the image dataset I have is quiet huge and loading it on the GPU each time, I think is taking up alot of time.

Comment: Are you certain you have emough GPU memory to hold the entire dataset on GPU memory and train the model?

Comment: Yes, I'm working with a RTX 4090 which has 24 GB of memory, The models are mostly lightweight custom architectures so I don't think memory would be a problem

Comment: Note that image data is heavily compressed - a `512 x 512` RGB image might be just a couple dozen kilobytes on disk, but requires 3 MB of vRAM when loaded on a GPU as a floating-point tensor.